# Insert a word in a matrix starting from an intersection

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I'm relatively new to the OOP world and Java (I've started a course on my university this semester about this whole thing) and I have a question about inserting a word in a matrix starting from an intersection.

So, I have, let's say, 2 Strings inside an array of Strings that need to be inserted in a 10x10 char matrix (which actually is a crossword) and let's say that the words inside this array of strings are "traceroute" and "employee". Those words can actually be filled in if they satifsy the following conditions:

1) they mustn't be larger than the matrix size (i.e., words[n].length() > matrix.length);
2) they must be fully inserted to be considered okay (i.e., if they find a black cell like the '#' char, the method should change column and line where to look).

What I'd like to have is something like what's inside this pastebin link http://pastebin.com/zKzUK6Pe .

I'm trying to develop an algorithm to do that but I'm stuck: I've tried to look for solutions online but they're not explained and I just don't want to copy and paste. I'd like to learn *why* that happens and how to avoid it. For know, I'm focusing myself on doing something "not OO".

This is what I've done so far

```
    public void setWord(String[] words) {
    /*
     * 
     * From input, I receive a String arrays which holds two words --->
     * 
     * 
     * String[] daWords = { "traceroute", "pippo"};
     * 
     * At this point, I thought to create a new boolean var(which I actually turned into an array)
     * which, when it'll be setted to true, will tell to the crossword to change word in order to
     * avoid an ongoing printing of the same string.

     */

    boolean[] hasItBeenUsed = { false, false, false, false};
    //the indexes of the strings array and of the boolean array
    /*
     * 
     * Essentialy, the boolean array must have a correspondence with the string one.
     * In a better way: hasItBeenUsed[0] will become true <=> words[0] has been fully
     * inserted inside the crossword.
     */
    int counterForBoolArr = 0;
    int counterForStringArr = 0;


for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {


        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            /*
             * Variable which, according to my twisted mind, should represent the end of the insertion
             * of the current word
             */
            boolean breaking = words[counterForStringArr].length() < j;
            /*
             * If the element situated in pos matrix[i][j] doesn't contain a blackcell(#) and the
             * boolean variable is setted to false...
             */

            if (matrix[i][j] != '#' && !breaking) {
                //Add in matrix[i][j] the char contained in words[counterForStringArr].charAt(j)
                matrix[i][j] = words[counterForStringArr].charAt(j);
            } else {
                //Continue the iteration and do not consider this case
                continue;
            }
            //If the boolean variable is actually setted to true...
                if (breaking) {
                    /*
                     * I check if the char contained in matrix[i][j] is the same of the given word from the Strings array.
                     * If it's a yes, the element contained in hasItBeenUsed[counterForBoolArr] will be setted either to true or false.
                     * 
                     */


                    hasItBeenUsed[counterForBoolArr] = matrix[i][j] == words[counterForStringArr].charAt(j) ? true : false;

                    /*
                     * Increasing the indexes in order to pass to the next correspondence between String-boolean
                     */


                    counterForBoolArr++;
                    counterForStringArr++;
                    }

        }

    }

}
```

What I get from this method is a crossword matrix populated only by one single word, "traceroute", and that is not actually the output that I'd like to have and I don't know how to stop that or skipping to the next word. I thought that, declaring the boolean breaking variable would have helped me in achieving that goal but it looks like that the only thing that I've done is making this code more unreadable. I thought as well of using the "break ;" formula but it will only print one word and that's it.

Could someone please help me by giving suggestions on how I should correctly write this alghoritm?

Anything would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to fill in a crossword puzzle answer?  If so, that is an **extremely** complicated algorithm for a beginner.  You have to try each word in **all** the locations, stop when a word won't fit, **start over** with a different word, until you've tried **all combinations of all words**.

Comment: Yes @GilbertLeBlanc , I'm trying to do that because it was given as an homework. How can I achieve the "stop when a word won't fit" part? I've thought of keeping track of how many characters of that word have been inserted in the crossword and then comparing the length of the string and the number that the variable for the tracking is holding. Might that be a valid approach?

Comment: "How can I achieve the "stop when a word won't fit" part?" Get the size of the horizontal or vertical area from the matrix and see if the word fits.  Break your code up into tiny, easy to test methods, or you will never complete the assignment.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion @GilbertLeBlanc!